# Django Database querying

Tags: python, django, database

I'm having an issue here that I want clarification with, see, I'm making a program that does analysis of data.
I wanted to query data from different users, the data is numerical by the way, whenever I'd get subject marks from a user, I want the system to return the name of the user who has those marks.
It was all working fine until I tried querying the users with the same marks, and all I could get was an error

```
analyzer.models.ResultsALevel.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one 
ResultsALevel -- it returned 4!
```

So I was trying to find a way to still query and return the name of users with that subject mark, even if they have the same marks.
I believe that should be possible since the users have different id's and stuff, help would be much appreciated!

Here's my views.py

```
biology_marks = []
    for student in ResultsALevel.objects.all():
        biology_marks.append(student.advanced_biology_1)
    value_1_biology = 
ResultsALevel.objects.get(advanced_biology_1=biology_marks[-1]).student_name.last_name
    value_2_biology = 
ResultsALevel.objects.get(advanced_biology_1=biology_marks[-2]).student_name.last_name
    value_3_biology = 
ResultsALevel.objects.get(advanced_biology_1=biology_marks[-3]).student_name.last_name
    value_4_biology = 
ResultsALevel.objects.get(advanced_biology_1=biology_marks[-4]).student_name.last_name
```

Answer (score 1):

ObjectManager.get() is used to retrieve single instances, usually selected by a primary key field.

Using ObjectManager.get() on a field where multiple data exists which matches the query, an error is returned (MultipeObjectsReturned)

Use ObjectManager.filter() in stead.

Comment: I will try that and I'll let you if it works. Though I don't think this solve my problem entirely as I need a way to query subjects marks and be able to distinguish from which user the marks belong. How do I do that?